# Too few parameters. (1) expected

Tags: sql, ms-access, parameters, vba

I'm using VBA to pass a parameter to a stored query, but keep getting the error. Here is the stored query:

```sql
PARAMETERS Parm1 Long;
UPDATE tJ010_SRP4Codes INNER JOIN tZ100_VendorProfiles 
ON tJ010_SRP4Codes.SRP4Code = tZ100_VendorProfiles.JdeSRP4Code 
SET tJ010_SRP4Codes.Vendor = 'TEST'
WHERE ((([Parm1]=tZ100_VendorProfiles.VendorID)));
```

Here is the VBA that calls the query:

```vb
Dim Parm1 As Long
db.QueryDefs(!QueryName).Parameters(Parm1) = intVdrProfileID
db.Execute !QueryName, dbFailOnError
```

I've tried with and without the "Parameters..." line in the stored query. Same error both ways.
The stored query works fine on it's own, just not when called from VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `DAO.QueryDef` object, supply the parameter value, and execute the `QueryDef`

```vb
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs(!QueryName)
qdf.Parameters("Parm1").Value = intVdrProfileID
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
```

`Parameters("Parm1")` means the parameter named *Parm1*.  Without quotes there, `Parameters(Parm1)`, Access would interpret *Parm1* to be a variable.  If you don't have such a variable, that would throw an error.

It's also possible to identify a parameter by number instead of name.  The numbering is zero-based, so `Parameters(0)` means the first parameter.

Note I assumed `!QueryName` is a recordset value and is the name of a saved query.  And I don't know where *intVdrProfileID* comes from, but assume it's valid for the parameter value.

Comment: The addition of the double quotes around "Parm1" and adding ".value" didn't hurt, but changing "db.execute" to "qdf.execute" made everything work.

Comment: With `Dim Parm1 As Long`, `Parm1` is initialized to zero.  Then if you don't assign it a different value later, `Parameters(Parm1)` would be the same as `Parameters(0)` So yes, that could work in this situation, but I didn't believe that's what you actually meant for *Parm1*.  And if that is what you intended all along, I think it might be less confusing to just use `Parameters(0)` in the first place.